# Обоснованность запятой перед тире на примерах текста

Tags: пунктуация

В одном романе Набокова регулярно используется запятая перед тире. Как мне кажется, в большинстве случаев она не обоснована (по крайней мере, не вижу причин, почему нельзя обойтись обычным тире).

Ниже приведены три случайно выбранных отрывка с примерами такого употребления. Будьте добры, объясните на основе текста по каким соображениям корректоры, редакторы, сам автор используют данную пунктуационную конструкцию.

Примеры:

1).Иногда вступает какой-нибудь посторонний Зет, — вносит и свою эпистолярную лепту, однако только ради того, чтобы растолковать читателю (не глядя, впрочем, на него, оставаясь к нему в профиль) событие, которое без ущерба для естественности или по какой другой причинe ни Икс, ни Игрек не могли бы в письмe разъяснить. Да и они пишут не без оглядки, — всe эти «Помнишь, как тогда-то и там-то…» (слeдует обстоятельное воспоминание) вводятся не столько для того, чтобы освeжить память корреспондента, сколько для того, чтобы дать читателю нужную справку, — так что в общем картина получается довольно комическая, — особенно, повторяю, смeшны эти аккуратно выписанные и ни к черту ненужные даты, — и когда в концe вдруг протискивается Зет, чтобы написать своему личному корреспонденту (ибо в таком романe переписываются рeшительно всe) о смерти Икса и Игрека или о благополучном их соединении, то читатель внезапно чувствует, что всему этому предпочел бы самое обыкновенное письмо от налогового инспектора. Вообще говоря, я всегда был надeлен недюжинным юмором, — дар воображения связан с ним; горе тому воображению, которому юмор не сопутствует.

2).Могу продолжать, — соскользнуло под стол.

3).Мое почтенное от шестнадцатого написано от руки, — я писал на почтамтe, — так взволновался, получив отвeт на мое почтенное от девятого, что не мог отложить до возможности настукать, — да и особых причин стeсняться своих почерков (у меня их нeсколько) еще не было, — я знал, что в конечном счетe получателем окажусь я.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Сам автор" давно и прочно забыл русский язык, у него даже словоупотребление встречается ошибочное... Хотя приведённые Вами цитаты из романа, написанного в 1934 году - на излёте его русскоязычного творчества.

Трилингва был Владимир Владимирович, с младенчества.

> **Набоков о себе**
>
> ...Я американский писатель, рождённый в России, получивший образование
>   в Англии, где я изучал французскую литературу перед тем, как на
>   пятнадцать лет переселиться в Германию.
>
> ...Моя голова разговаривает по-английски, моё сердце — по-русски, и
>   моё ухо — по-французски.

Ваш коллега по недоумению:

> За последнее время прочитала многое из Набокова, где меня напрягла
>   пунктуация, но это, наверно, «чисто авторское», бог с ним. А вот в
>   связи с «Лолитой» (изд-во «ЭКСМО») возникло много вопросов по
>   орфографии. Ошибок столько, что слов нет. Сначала удивлялась молча,
>   потом, когда поняла, что без помощи «Вече» не разобраться, стала
>   выписывать примеры. (Список, конечно, неполный.) Попыталась
>   сгруппировать ошибки по возможным причинам — не получилось. Итак
>   подряд: палиатив и паллиатив, целофан, шеколадный, толчек, новичек,
>   юбченка, башмачек, безстрастный, безвкусный и бесвкусный, разсудок,
>   оффициальный, досчатый, ношенный, потрепаный, резко-голосая,
>   до-кембрийский, видити-ли, повидимому, кто-бы, тутже, темже,
>   сорок-девятый, юговосточный, супер-обаятельный, отвести вместо отвезти
>   (по контексту), нос незаложен, не дооценивал… Разъясните мне,
>   пожалуйста, вот когда издательство решило издать классика, откуда
>   берутся тексты, правятся ли они и до какой степени? Вот, скажем, хочу
>   Льва Толстого напечатать. Где исходник? Кто решает: ошибка имеет место
>   благодаря тому, что правописание слова изменилось со временем или
>   тому, что автор неграмотный (в частности вот слово «оффициальный» — то
>   ли это чистая ошибка, то ли это у Набокова благодаря влиянию
>   английского языка, то ли тогда это слово и по-русски так писалось, как
>   было, например, со словом «шоффер» — в таких случаях править или
>   нет?). Ошибаться ведь, наверное, и Набоков мог, несмотря на
>   мастерство. Или классики вообще неприкасаемы?

Так, о корректорах и редакторах, к коим я принадлежу.

Корректор может сгоряча понавыбрасывать лишние знаки; на пятом-десятом-пятнадцатом ***повторяющемся*** "странном" знаке зап-тире (как он называется у полиграфистов) страдалец побежит к редактору с воплем типо что бы это значило.

И редактор, тяжко вздохнув, приканчивает всю етую самодеятельность, ласково прошелестев сделавшему попытку зарваться корректору: хозяин - барин...

По-другому: авторская пунктуация мэтра, руками не трогать.

Зато набоковеды сочиняют об том диссертации: они тоже кушать хочут, а он им хлебушок-от подал, тёпленьким...

> ...Постановка тире на месте, не предусмотренном правилом, имеет свою
>   причину: сознательное намерение автора выразить такой смысловой
>   оттенок, которого могло бы в данном случае и не быть и которого
>   читатель и не ожидает. Такая постановка знака «тире» отражается на
>   структуре художественного текста. Этот пунктуационный знак стал
>   элементом набоковской стилистики. По наблюдениям А. М. Пешковского,
>   чтению знака «тире» характерна «фигура увеличения с следующей резкой и
>   внезапной паузой»...

- [К вопросу об авторском оформлении текстов художественных произведений](http://www.moluch.ru/conf/phil/archive/78/3244/)
- [ПРИЕМЫ СОЗДАНИЯ ЭКСПРЕССИВНОЙ ФУНКЦИИ АВТОРСКОГО ТИРЕ В. НАБОКОВА](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/priemy-sozdaniya-ekspressivnoy-funktsii-avtorskogo-tire-v-nabokova)
- [ОБ ОДНОМ ФАКТЕ АВТОРСКОЙ ПУНКТУАЦИИ В РОМАНЕ В. В. НАБОКОВА «ЛОЛИТА»](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/ob-odnom-fakte-avtorskoy-punktuatsii-v-romane-v-v-nabokova-lolita)
- [Леденев А. Выразительные возможности авторской пунктуации в произведениях В. Набокова // Stefanos: Сб. научн. работ памяти А.Г. Соколова. — МАКС Пресс Москва, 2008. — С. 195–204.](https://istina.msu.ru/publications/article/5828736/)

  ---

Насчёт вмешательства редактора в текст, где правку невозможно согласовать с автором по причине кончины оного: «Советские текстологи считают, что следует с особым уважением относиться к последней авторской воле...»

[**Хозяйке на заметку:**](http://feb-web.ru/feb/classics/critics/eixenbaum/eih/eih-427-.htm)

> Осведомленному и опытному текстологу, например, совершенно ясно, что
>   имеющиеся в автографе «Героя нашего времени» такие формы, как
>   «аглицкую», «колена», «взойдя в комнату», «приподымая», «подымаясь» и
>   пр., представляют собой живые факты лермонтовского языка, тогда как
>   появившиеся в печати «исправления» (войдя, приподнимая и т. п.) —
>   обыкновенная корректорская правка, которую текстологи обязаны снимать.
>   Автор статьи «с удовлетворением» отмечает, что в последнем издании
>   Гослитиздата «большая часть указанных погрешностей в тексте романа
>   устранена». Тут он выдал себя с головой: испытанное им
>   «удовлетворение» характерно не для текстолога, а для корректора,
>   всегда старающегося подчинить живую речь книжным правилам грамматики.
>   По-корректорски обошелся автор статьи и с другими двумя случаями,
>   утверждая, что взятые мною из автографа поправки представляют собою
>   «явную языковую оплошность» Лермонтова...